# Native installation of Ubuntu on Apple M1 (without USB drive)

Tags: apple

Corellium recently made a [show case on how to run Ubuntu on the Apple M1](https://www.corellium.com/blog/linux-m1) ARM processors. This seems to work on most of the M1 machines. However, Ubuntu is booted from USB drive and the internal hard drive is not available. If you remove the USB drive, Ubuntu will neither boot, nor work as expected.

I am looking for a way to install Ubuntu on the internal hard drive.

Comment: In the link it says "Tutorial for NVME Boot ( Works on Mac Mini/Pro/Air )"  what do you believe NVME is?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes. Booting from NVME is not what I am looking for.

Comment: but those are the options: either USB -OR- NVME/PCI Express/harddisk=ssd. There are no other options.